# calling sql stored procedures in DotNetNuke

Tags: sql-server-2008, dotnetnuke-module

I have a problem here where i cannot call stored procedure in DNN.I am using DNN 7[lastest].I tried using NamePrefix + "reg_user" but it appear not to call the procedure that I want.Below is what I tried but comes to the same result.

**SqlDataProvider.cs[DAL]**

```
public override void AddUser(int ModuleId,string User_name,string User_password,string User_email  {
    SqlHelper.ExecuteNonQuery(ConnectionString,GetFullyQualifiedName("reg_user"),ModuleId,User_name,User_password,User_email);
}
```

**FeatureController.cs[BL]**

```
Public void AddUser(Register_user reg){
    if(reg._User_name.Trim() != "")
    {
        DataProvider.Instance().AddUser(reg.ModuleId,reg._User_name,reg.User_password,_User_email);    
    }
}
```

**Register_user.cs[Entity]**

```
public class Register_user
{
    public int _ModuleId{ get; set; }
    public string _User_name{ get; set; }
    public string _User_password{ get; set; }
    public string _User_email{ get; set; }
}
```

**view.ascx.cs[UI]**

```
protected void btnregister_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    try
    {
        FeatureController cntrl = new FeatureController();
        Register_user reg = new Register_user()
        {
            _ModuleId=ModuleId,
            _User_name = txtusername.Text,
            _User_email = txtemail.Text,
            _User_password = txtpassword.Text
        };
        cntrl.AddUser(reg);
        }
        catch (Exception ee)
        {
            lblresult.Text = ee.Message.ToString();
        }
}
```

Error: The store procedure 'dbo.DNNModule2_reg_user' doesn't exist.

Any helps are much appriciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am back with solution update for this question that I asked few days ago.
The solution for this is rather simple.Here is what i need to change.And it will call Sql database without any problem.

```
public override void AddUser(int ModuleId,string User_name,string User_password,string User_email  {
    SqlHelper.ExecuteNonQuery(ConnectionString,DatabaseOwner + ObjectQualifier + reg_user",ModuleId,User_name,User_password,User_email);
}
```

Just change from **GetFullyQualifiedName** to **DatabaseOwner + ObjectQualifier**.
I am doing this as a part of good community members.So I tend not to left my question unanswered.

Regrads,

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to look at once on your SqlDataProvider.

private const string providerType = "data";

**private const string moduleQualifier = "Objectqualifier_";**

this is object qualifier string which added with your SP name like
Objectqualifier_SPname.
and you have to Create SP with same way.
Means you have to Write only last part of sp name in
GetFullyQualifiedName("SPname").
Use debugger to check full name of SP.
and then check your original SP name which is in SQL Server.

Will you please provide me your sp name as in your SQL Server and your
*private const string moduleQualifier